# How do i update boolean field on Django model?

Tags: python, django

I have implemented a view that is supposed to update two boolean fields on a Django model  i.e is_published and submitted. However , currently, the view is only able to update the first boolean field(`is_published`) and leaves out the second one(`submitted`). What am i doing wrong and how can I implement a solution that updates both fields at the same time?

Here is my code

Model

```
class Course(models.Model):

    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View

```
class UpdateVideoAPIPublishView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    """ Update course """

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = (CourseJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        course = get_object_or_404(
                Course, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

        if not course.is_published:
            course.is_published = True
            course.submitted = False
            course.save()
            return Response(
                {"message": "Course updated succesfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            'Course already published'
        )
```

Comment: In your view code submitted is set to False

Comment: Hello @xplo4d, there is a view that comes before this which sets submitted to `True`, So I use this view to get `submitted` field back to it's original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
if not course.is_published:
      course.is_published = True
      course.save()
 if not course.submitted:
      course.submitted = True
      course.save()
```

Also as the @brunodesthuilliers  said in the comments you can do it like this also :

```
if not course.is_published and not course.submitted:
          course.is_published = True
          course.submitted = True
          course.save()
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Can you explain a bit why the code I wrote at first was not working?

Comment: Because you only did it for `is_published` but not for `submitted.`

Comment: And this makes two full update queries... you should only call `save()` once here, and pass the ` update_fields` arguments to only update the changed field(s).